# Joomla Jquery not working, why is that?

Tags: jquery, joomla

I installed joomla 2.5 genuine installation, but JQuery not working.How can i get JQuery working in joomla ? is default JQuery library not comming with joomla ?

Comment: how did you know that JQuery not working ?

Comment: once run $('body') in console it returns null, it means jquery library is not there! isn't it ?

Comment: @Gihan Dilusha - Joomla use mootools by default, but we can add (use) jquery in joomla. The question is where you are using jquery i mean in templates or extensions. Another main issue is many time mootools and jquery conflicts.

Comment: @Happy Singh -  is it ok if i put the jquery in the template ?

Comment: @GihanDilusha yes you can put it in the template - but if you don't need it in most of the articles it will be considered as bad practice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add jquery like this in templates -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE_NAME/PATH_TO_JAVASCRIPT_FOLDER/YOUR_JQUERY.js"></script>
```

- YOUR TEMPLATE - Name of you template
- PATH TO JAVASCRIPT FOLDER - If any folder present then the path of the folder
- YOUR JQUERY.js - Finally the file name which one you want to include.

Comment: +1 for good answer, but when giving path examples, you should always recommend no-space directory and file names: `/path/to_next/dir`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the jQuery Easy plugin for joomla. This will enable jQuery and/or jQuery UI in front and/or backend silently. Get it here http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/scripts/18327

If i'm not wrong this plugin handles the noConflict issue with mootools.

Answer (score 2):

```
$document = &JFactory::getDocument();
$componentDir = JURI::base();

$document->addStyleSheet($componentDir.'/templates/movm/css/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css' );
$document->addStyleSheet($componentDir.'/templates/movm/css/comman.css');
$document->addScript($componentDir.'/templates/movm/js/jquery.min.js' );
$document->addScript($componentDir.'/templates/movm/js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js' );
$document->addCustomTag( '<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>' );
```

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention: by default, jQuery uses $ as a shortcut for jQuery

Becasue Joomla use Mootools if you want to use also jQuery you must write JQuery instead of $.

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the docs at http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_JavaScript

There are "two ways" to include a JavaScript file using the Joomla API.

```
<?php
$document = &JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript('/media/system/js/sample.js');
?>
```

or

```
<?php
// Add the path parameter if the path is different than 'media/system/js/'
JHTML::script('sample.js', 'templates/custom/js/');
?>
```

Using these methods is highly recommended as it clearly differentiates another scripting language (JavaScript) from the main PHP code, ensures all JavaScript is correctly embedded between the  tags and, in the case of JDocument::addScript and JHTML::script ensures that a JavaScript file is included only once (I.e. there is no .js file duplication).