# Jquery codes dont work in Joomla, tried everything found on google

Tags: jquery, joomla

I want to wrap my img with a span and set the image to be the span's background image so I can do some css trick to the image. I found this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("img").load(function() {
        $(this).wrap(function(){
            return '<span class="image-wrap ' + $(this).attr('class') + '"'+'style="position:relative; display:inline-block; background:url(' + $(this).attr('src') + ') no-repeat center center; width: ' + $(this).width() + 'px; height: ' + $(this).height() + 'px;" />';
        });
        $(this).css("opacity","0");
    });
});
</script>
```

and it worked perfect well in a single html file. 
However, when I added this code to my ~/template/index.php, it didn't work and browser reported:

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'ready'

It seemed the Jquery wasn't properly loaded, I tried to add the following code to my index.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and also tried installing Jquery Easy plugin and enable it, but none of them worked.

What is wrong?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706093/jquery-error-uncaught-typeerror-object-htmldocument-has-no-method-ready) it sounds like a similar situation.

Comment: can you provide a link to your site, else check to see if 2 jquery files are being imported as this might cause conflicts

Comment: Which Joomla! version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

have a look here at a similar issue / solution:
[Joomla Jquery not working, why is that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544895/joomla-jquery-not-working-why-is-that)

> You can add jquery like this in templates -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE_NAME/PATH_TO_JAVASCRIPT_FOLDER/YOUR_JQUERY.js"></script>

YOUR TEMPLATE - Name of you template
PATH TO JAVASCRIPT FOLDER - If any folder present then the path of the folder
YOUR JQUERY.js - Finally the file name which one you want to include.
```

Comment: gwww... I tried everything.. none worked.
 I tried using the code you gave me, I tried replacing $ with jquery, but its still  reporting "Uncaught Reference error: jquery is not defined"

Comment: it uses mootools by default. maybe you have a conflict. here 3 posts that address this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13040218/1807551, http://stackoverflow.com/q/1329981/1807551, http://stackoverflow.com/q/2810399/1807551

Comment: Did you try replacing $ with jQuery (not jquery)? Check the capitalization

Comment: this finally worked:
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
add the above code before jquery codes and replace $ with $j

Answer (score 0):

You can add jquery like this in page -

$document->addScriptDeclaration("
//

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("img").load(function(){
    $(this).wrap(function(){
        return '<span class="image-wrap ' + $(this).attr('class') + '"'+'style="position:relative; display:inline-block; background:url(' + $(this).attr('src') + ') no-repeat center center; width: ' + $(this).width() + 'px; height: ' + $(this).height() + 'px;" />';
    });
    $(this).css("opacity","0");
});
```

});

//]]>

");

And also You can declare jquery like this in templates index page -

baseurl ?>/templates/template;?>/Your JS Folder/Your Java Script.js">